# calculate with matrix

Tags: matrices

Hello guys can someone help me with that please ? And thanks for that

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 &  1 \\  0 & 1 & 1 \\  0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$

and we have

$B = A − I. \tag 2$

Calculate $B^n$ for $n ∈ N$ and deduct from that the expression of $A^n$.

Comment: the matrix is equal to that:

A = (1 1 1)
       (0 1 1)
       (0 0 1)

Comment: the last  bracket  means the end of the first  line . Actually A is a matrix (3x3)

Comment: This will help you with the formatting. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Aita, suggest you find $B^2$ and $B^3$ yourself. Easier than you might think

Comment: Thanks Doug M and Will yes i already found them and i have for$B^2$   = $$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$   and  $B^3 = 0$

Comment: Aita, since $I$ commutes with anything, it means you can calculate $A^n = (I+B)^n$ by ordinary binomial expansion

Comment: Aita, let me emphasize that, if we have two square matrices that do NOT commute, we cannot use binomials. If $EF \neq FE,$ then $(E+F)^2 = E^2 + EF + FE + F^2,$ and we cannot combine the mixed terms. However, in your case, also the case of Jordan Normal Form, also the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition, we get to use binomial expansion, and this ends in a fixed number of terms because one of the matrices is "nilpotent."

Comment: alright guys thank you for help